# How to create a class with Spring Roo that extends a class that expects a type parameter?

Tags: oop, generics, spring-roo, type-parameter

For example, org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable needs the type of a public key. I have tried things like:

```
roo> entity jpa --class ~.model.Foo --extends org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable<Long>
```

but they just give errors such as:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert 'org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable<Long>' to type JavaType for option 'extends' Illegal name 'org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable<Long>' (illegal character)
```

I could circumvent the problem (of needing to provide a type parameter) by creating a new class Bar.

```
class Bar extends org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable<Long> {}
```

and let Foo extend Bar.

```
roo> entity jpa --class ~.model.Foo --extends ~.model.Bar
```

But then I would loose all benefits of type parameters.

Does a workable solution exists for the above question? If so, what would that be?

Just as a side note: in an ideal world I would like my domain classes to extend the following AbstractAuditableEntity.

```
public abstract class AbstractAuditableEntity<U, PK extends java.io.Serializable> 
    extends org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable<PK> 
    implements org.springframework.data.domain.Auditable<U, PK> {
// some private fields, setters and getters...
}
```

Comment: Could you just create the entity with no extends, then add it after the fact?  You will loose the logging, but I would think it should work.

Comment: @CodeChimp: edditing the generated code will work. I'm interested in generating as much code as possible (who isn't), and extending all model classes isn't something that would make me very happy... Someone said that in version 1.2.4 of Spring Roo more OOP features will become available which will hopefully help me out.